# Is it possible to set a gtk theme for flatpak apps independet from the Gnome theme configuration?

Tags: themes, gtk3, flatpak

Is it possible to set a gtk theme for flatpak apps independent from the Gnome theme configuration?

For Gnome I am using the POP! Slim theme, which is not available in the flatpak theme repo yet. Only the dark and light slim version is available there. For Flatpak apps, I could live with the normal giant POP! theme, which is already available in the flatpak theme repo. Right now the only way that works for me to set the POP! theme for Flatpak is by setting my whole Gnome theme to Pop! standard.

Is there a different way to handle the flatpak gtk theme independently from the Gnome setting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

A simple method is to install a theme, and it will switch to newest installed theme automatically.

e.g.

`flatpak install org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru`